# Ruby module with rspec to randomise weather

Tags: ruby, rspec, module

I'm new to rspec and modules and i've been having problems with this since fri. I want to create a module that i can call/pass to my Airport.rb file to randomise the weather between "sunny" and "stormy". I'm having issues working with rspec so any resource recommendations are welcomed.

weather keeps being return by rspec as an undefined variable.

weather.rb(module)

```
    module Weather
      def reading?
        weather = ["Sunny", "Stormy"]
        weather.sample
      end
    end
```

Spec:

```
require './lib/weather'

class WeatherHolder; include Weather; end

describe Weather do

  let(:holder) {WeatherHolder.new}

  it "should read the weather" do
    expect(weather).to eq(reading)
  end
end
```

Comment: can you post a little more code, maybe your _spec.rb file would help.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin thanks for editing my spec file and not just deleting it like the other guy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let(:holder) {WeatherHolder.new}` should be    `let(:weather) {WeatherHolder.new}`
and then you need to figure out how to call the `reading?` function on the weather variable.

Try something like

```
describe Weather do

  let(:weather) {WeatherHolder.new}

  it "should read the weather" do
    expect(["Sunny", "Stormy"]).to include(weather.reading?)
  end
end
```

This works on my computer.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. It's getting my head around what rspec needs me to write to reflect the string statement after `it` that's causing me problems.

Comment: Yeah, and actually my code is not a good example of what you should be  doing. I don't use RSpec much, but you would most likely want to place an instance variable in the Weather class to contain the Array, and then you would use something like `expect(weather.weather_types).to include(weather.reading?)` Oh and on that topic, you should definitely remove the ? after the reading when you declare the method. ? should only be used for boolean returns. You return a string, so somebody else using your code will get confused when the method returns a string instead of a boolean.

Comment: Accidentally deleted my comment: The 1st test should be this i think `expect(weather.reading).to be_true ` and then the 2nd test would pass in the string. Then refactor into one test with the code you suggested .

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined `weather` in your spec, nor `reading` for that matter. Presumably you want an `expect` expression that involves `holder.reading?`.